# Reference to static const data objects

Tags: c++

I have a set of utility classes that store static const data members. Now I need to use these data members in functional classes. I am planning to use references (dont want pointers) to the static const objects, but keep getting the error below. Can you please point out the logical/technical mistake in the code?

```
#include <string>

class staticData
{
  public:
   static const int cs = 1;
   static const staticData data1;

  private:
   staticData(int id_): _id(id_)   //NOTE: Private constructer, static access only!!
   { }

   int _id;
};

const staticData staticData::data1(1001);

class testReference
{
  public:
    testReference(): _member(staticData::data1)
    {}

  private:
    staticData& _member;
};
```

**invalid initialization of reference of type âstaticData&â from expression of type âconst staticDataâ**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to reference a `const` object through a non-const reference.

Thus, the original object can be modified through the reference, as the reference is non-`const`, and thus you're breaking the contract you made when declaring the object as `const`.

There are 2 options:

- remove the `const` from `static const staticData data1;`
- make the reference `const`: `const staticData& _member;`

EDIT:

As per your comment, you can have:

```
class testReference
{
  public:
    testReference(): _member(&staticData::data1)
    {}

  private:
    staticData const * _member;
};
```

This way, you can change what `_member` points to (not possible with references), but you can't change the object itself.

Comment: I want to keep static const staticData data1, but want to be able to change what _member might refer to. Is that possible?

Comment: @vid no. A reference cannot be changed to refer to a different object. It will always refer to `data1`. You could use a pointer for that though.

Comment: Thank you. In fact i could use static staticData data1, and make all data members private - this will make it essentially immutable, and can use references. Is that fine?

Comment: @vid again, if you use references, you can't re-assign them. And no. Although it might work, **you shouldn't remove the `const` just to make it compile**. Is that object ever going to change? If not, make it `const`.

Answer (score 1):

`_member` is a reference allowing mutation.  `data1` is immutable.  It's impossible to provide a writable view of a read-only object.